# ngCordova file_uri to base64

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm trying to use ngCordova's camera plugin (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) to get pictures from my iphone and send it to my server. The backend developer wants me to encode it to base64. my data model looks like this

```
[{image_name:"foo", link: //base64 string}]
```

this is what my code looks like

```
$scope.getPictureFromGallery = function() {  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {


     $scope.image = imageURI;


    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

  };
```

Comment: Just add `.toDataURL("image/png");` to your image uri. E.g. `$scope.image = imageURI.toDataURL("image/png");`

Comment: what does image/png mean... i want it in jpeg

Comment: `image/png` it's just an option if you want to use/convert it to `png, jpeg, etc`. Or you can also remove that just use `.toDataURL();` then done.

Comment: would this be correct... $scope.image = imageURI.toDataURL("image/jpg");

Comment: Yes, but I suggest if you want to use the default file extension just use `.toDataURL();`. E.g. `$scope.image = imageURI.toDataURL();`

Comment: I just checked the plugin you're using and the result image was already in byte format so you just need to add `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"`. E.g. `$scope.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the documentation states that you can just set the destinationType to get the proper results.

```
module.controller('PictureCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, // <== HERE
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; // <== HERE is how you create the actual string to send to server
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });

  }, false);
});
```

I have a complete working example here https://github.com/aaronksaunders/dcww/blob/master/www/js/services.js#L39

Comment: Thanks .. How do i make the inage display in my view after i selected it.. If my destination type is file uri im able to display it in the view if data url im not

Comment: `image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;`